# Cannot able to post value to another page in php? using url?

Tags: php, url, post, header, location

cannot able to post value using this method in php.i want post value to one page to another page.it gives empty results.

```
header("location:http://webpage.com/retry.php?amount=".$amount);
```

Comment: try `var_dump($_REQUEST);` on your retry.php

Comment: What do you want to do? Get the value of `amount`?

Comment: To get the value of something in the `URL`, use `$_GET`. I think you are using `$_POST`, based from the title

Comment: Result of redirected url .     https://webpage.com/retry.php?amount:

Comment: first i want post data. value is cannot posted.

Comment: i don't know why this not working

Comment: what happens when you do a `print_r($_GET['amount']);` ? Also verify that `$amount` is not empty

Comment: Also, does the `header` line actually perform a redirect?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply `POST` a data to another PHP file from a PHP file using `header()`. You need to use a function/API called the `cURL`

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.example.com/tester.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "postvar1=value1&postvar2=value2&postvar3=value3");

// in real life you should use something like:
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
//          http_build_query(array('postvar1' => 'value1')));

// receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

// further processing ....
if ($server_output == "OK") { ... } else { ... }

?>
```

---

If you cannot write this big code each time and debug the errors, I recommened you using UniREST client for this work. It's simple, straightforward, light and does the work for us.

Download [UniREST from here](http://unirest.io/php.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
if(trim($amount)!=''){ // Check if amount is not empty. 
    // Redirect to page
    header("location:http://webpage.com/retry.php?amount=".$amount);
}
```

Comment: Serioulsy? This anwer is wrong. You cannot send a POST request using 'header('Location: blahblahblah')`.

Comment: actually you can. OP probably is passing an empty variable

Comment: Yes you can do this

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.